# What does the bitcoin username & password refers to?

Tags: blockchain, php

I want to integrate bitcoin to a website to receive payments. I am going to use easyBitcoin (https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP). But i don't know what will be the username & password. Here is that line:

$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('username','password');

What does the bitcoin username & password refers to ? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the Bitcoin RPC username and password which you can configure in your bitcoin.conf file (if you're running Bitcoin Core) as follows:

```
rpcuser=<yourusername>
rpcpassword=<yourpassword>
```